# partition by multiple columns in Kusto

Tags: partitioning, kql, azure-data-explorer

I recently learned about `partition` function in Kusto but struggle to find a way to `partition` by **multiple columns**. Here is the case I'm failing to figure out:

I'm trying to fetch top 3 `account_executive_id` based on their `max_sales` by `billable_id`, `organization_id`, and `product`. But the KQL script below is returning results per each product across all `billable_id`, `organization_id`, and `products`.

```
table_1 
| where day>= ago(28d)
| summarize hint.strategy=shuffle max_sales=max(sales_amount) by billable_id, organization_id, product, account_executive_id
| partition hint.strategy=shuffle by product (top 3 by max_sales desc)
```

Would you please advise me how to achieve the outcome per each combination of `billable_id`, `organization_id`, and `product`?

Comment: Can you explain the requirement with sample input and output data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `partition` operator in Kusto only supports partitioning by a single column. To achieve your requirement of partitioning by multiple columns, you can concatenate all the columns into a single column and then use that column as a partitioning key in the query. Below is the sample query.

```
table_1
| summarize max_sales=max(sales_amount) by billable_id, organization_id, product, account_executive_id
| extend partition_columns= strcat(billable_id," | ",organization_id," | ",product )
| partition hint.strategy=shuffle by partition_columns (top 3 by max_sales desc)
```

Here, the  `extend`  operator concatenates the  `billable_id`,  `organization_id`, and  `product`  columns into a single column called  `partition_columns`, separated by the  `|`  character. And the  `partition`  operator partitions the data by the  `partition_columns`  column, and the  `top`  operator returns the top 3  `account_executive_id`  for each partition, based on the  `max_sales`  value.

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WU32qDMBTG732Kg1cKrmi6vw6fZAw5jWkbiFHMcbSlD7%2FEOudmYQwa8SJfEn%2Ff8ZB8ShAQbpQoMyigQsJBRRUec6sEyVoksJFKDZtklRvqpN4l0HQ71PKEJBs9n2%2B7puo5TRo5b3pNpTgI3pP8%2BAExqIQpsXY78k6gioO3AOzz5R2xlLG7NLNvnEA4K6TMQjthq5jGo%2FNFfNs5maXpKk18kJkXMvNGXlu5vg2ZLbtx74Xs5IMXsuvG47%2FIbEZmf5yNJy9kt%2Fbshey68XIb8pWzYe%2BgD7ST2Xi%2F31%2BDMcyCM5i%2BrrGTJwE1HsohaQo7iuaZE8PmOE%2B3RaxNeXY9yKyNOJDQFbTYkRw%2B4o3qa20KsCHHkaI5PoQzhMlvj8vsaASxhU402EtNK0uyDdsdC7Pvt1slXNULQ4ioaWHt1qYfhkoYHn8CfAGIDeUFAAA%3D)